# Any better popup modal framework in drupal

Tags: 7, javascript, chaos-tool-suite, forms

I use the [Chaos tool suite](http://drupal.org/project/ctools) module for modal popup in Drupal 7; I am unable to open popup from within a popup using ctools. Can it be done using ctools, or is there any better popup modal module in Drupal 7 which can do this? (I am using forms in popups and not only pages.)

Comment: For what do you need the dialog? Maybe you just need to code jQuery Dialog opening? Actualy there are some problems with popup modules (Dialog API, Popups API) in D7.

Comment: can u give me an example of how to use Dialog API to create a modal dialog, just a simple example, submit it as answer (not as comment) so that i can accept it

Comment: As I sayed, Dialog API is quite buggy in Drupal 7 for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could the [Colorbox](http://drupal.org/project/colorbox) module be useful for you?

> Colorbox is a light-weight, customizable lightbox plugin for jQuery 1.3 through 1.6. This module allows for integration of Colorbox into Drupal.